# Big Query: How to get top 20 correlations in a table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift, correlation, bigdata

I have 100,000 time-series files with a with 2 columns each, date, and value. I will make a table in Google BigQuery and append all time-series to this table so that each append will extend 3 columns, time_series_name, date, value. In the end, I will have 3 columns with millions of rows. What code would I have to use to the top 20 correlated time-series given a time_series_name. I think I would have to do some GROUPBY(time_series_name) and then calculate this time_series_name correlation with every other item, and then sort the items by descending. Is that right? What query code would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below,

It assumes you have your table named `all_time_series` with fields: `time_series_name`, `dt` and `value` and is built per logic you described in your question

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH series AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT time_series_name 
  FROM all_time_series
),
pairs AS (
  SELECT 
    series1.time_series_name AS time_series_1, 
    series2.time_series_name AS time_series_2,
    CONCAT(series1.time_series_name, ' - ', series2.time_series_name) AS pair_name 
  FROM series AS series1
  JOIN series AS series2
  ON series1.time_series_name < series2.time_series_name
) 
SELECT pair_name, CORR(value1, value2) AS correlation
FROM (
  SELECT pair_name, a1.dt AS dt, a1.value AS value1, a2.value AS value2
  FROM pairs AS p
  JOIN all_time_series AS a1 
    ON p.time_series_1 = a1.time_series_name
  JOIN all_time_series AS a2 
    ON p.time_series_2 = a2.time_series_name
    AND a1.dt = a2.dt
)
GROUP BY pair_name
ORDER BY correlation DESC
LIMIT 20
```

You can test above with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH all_time_series AS (
  SELECT 'a' AS time_series_name, '2016-01-01' AS dt, 1 AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', '2016-01-02', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', '2016-01-03', 3 UNION ALL

  SELECT 'b', '2016-01-01', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-01-02', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', '2016-01-03', 3 UNION ALL

  SELECT 'c', '2016-01-01', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', '2016-01-02', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', '2016-01-03', 7 UNION ALL

  SELECT 'd', '2016-01-01', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', '2016-01-02', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', '2016-01-03', 3
),
series AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT time_series_name 
  FROM all_time_series
),
pairs AS (
  SELECT 
    series1.time_series_name AS time_series_1, 
    series2.time_series_name AS time_series_2,
    CONCAT(series1.time_series_name, ' - ', series2.time_series_name) AS pair_name 
  FROM series AS series1
  JOIN series AS series2
  ON series1.time_series_name < series2.time_series_name
) 
SELECT pair_name, CORR(value1, value2) AS correlation
FROM (
  SELECT pair_name, a1.dt AS dt, a1.value AS value1, a2.value AS value2
  FROM pairs AS p
  JOIN all_time_series AS a1 
    ON p.time_series_1 = a1.time_series_name
  JOIN all_time_series AS a2 
    ON p.time_series_2 = a2.time_series_name
    AND a1.dt = a2.dt
)
GROUP BY pair_name
ORDER BY correlation DESC
LIMIT 2
```